# Visualforce page only visible if record is record type x else show normal page layout

Tags: visualforce, record-type

I only want this visualforce page to display if the record type of the record = "Historic R&D Project" or "Available R&D Project" or "Unavailable R&D Project". What else do I need to add into my code?

```
  <apex:page standardController="Product2">
    <apex:form>
       <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}" label="Project Name" /       >
         </apex:pageBlockSection>    
       </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Comment: Can you post your current logic being used within VF page?

Comment: apologies @TSmith I hadn't realised it didn't post

Comment: Seems like a job for Page Layouts. The Visualforce Page shouldn't care.

Answer (score 0):

Conditionally render the section of VF page based on RT.

You can basically check a controller variable (the Record Type in your case).

```
<apex:page standardController="Product2">
    <apex:form>
       <apex:pageBlock>
         <apex:pageBlockSection columns="2" rendered="{!recordType == '/* place your value here */'}">
            <apex:inputField Value="{!Product2.Name}" label="Project Name" /       >
         </apex:pageBlockSection>    
       </apex:pageBlock>
   </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

If it is equal to the RT you want to use for the specific panel then it renders the section. You can multiple checks and sections  with different fieldsets according to your requirement.

Comment: unfortunately that only removes the block, I want the visualforce page to appear when it's a certain record type e.g. 'unavailable R&D project'. And then use the normal page layout, when it's not any of the record types I've mentioned. how would i do that?